# Paste Special Overwrites Data Second Time through the Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a loop that filters a table based on a separate criteria list, then copies the filtered table to a new workbook, saves the workbook, and attaches it to an email.

The loop runs through the criteria list until done so it creates a few emails.

My problem is that the data copies correctly to the first new Workbook, but on subsequent Workbooks/Criteria, it does not.

What is frustrating is that on the line,

```
.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

it does copy the data (I can see it as I step through it), but the immediate line after,

```
.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
```

overwrites the data as blank cells.

However, this code works the first time through the loop so I'm not exactly sure where the loop is messing up. Any suggestions on this issue or on improving my code (I realize it is pretty messy) would be appreciated!

```
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow2 As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim agency As String
Dim lastRow3 As Long
Dim newWB As Workbook
Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim emailBody As String
Dim myolapp As Outlook.Application
Dim filename As String
Dim i As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim newWS As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set myolapp = Outlook.Application
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

Set sht = wb.ActiveSheet
lastRow = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Value = "Agency Code"
Range("A2").Formula = "=LEFT(B2, 3)"

Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & lastRow)

Columns("A:A").Copy
Set sht2 = Sheets.Add

sht2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False

ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
lastRow2 = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To lastRow2

    Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    Set newWS = newWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    agency = sht2.Range("A" & i)

    sht.Range("$A$1:$J$" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & agency, _
    Operator:=xlAnd

    lastRow3 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    sht.Range("B1:J" & lastRow3).Copy

    With newWS
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Rows("1:" & lastRow3).EntireRow.AutoFit

    newWB.SaveAs "C:\Users\dkmarsh\Desktop\" & agency & " Placement Stats"
    filename = newWB.FullName

    Set myItem = myolapp.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Placement (Agency) Templates\Placement Template.oft")
    emailBody = "Body"

    With myItem
        .Body = emailBody
        .Subject = agency & " Placement Files"
        .To = "you"
        .Attachments.Add filename
        .Display
    End With

    newWB.Close
    Kill filename

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Surely `xlPasteAll` includes column widths?

Comment: You need to qualify your ranges.  That means that every time you reference a cell, row, column, etc. you need to declare what sheet/workbook it is on.  You jump back and forth and may not be working on the sheet you intend.